# specify where an image is opened in subprocess

Tags: python

I am trying to use `subprocess` to open an image in a specific location on screen for example top left or top right...

```
import sys,subprocess
filename='handbag.jpg'
opener ="xdg-open"
subprocess.call([opener, filename])
```

How can I edit it so when it opens the image `subprocess.call([opener, filename])` to specify where to open

Comment: As far as I know `xdg-open` doesn't accept any location arguments. There's another command, [`xdg-settings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdg-settings.1.html) which _might_ support controlling it.

Comment: @martineau is there another way to open at certain locations (ideally using python built in)

Comment: No, I don't think so.